# How do I change the color of html text in my login form? (WTForms)

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask-wtforms

This is my html file where I render the template for my flask app:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <div>
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-5"></div>
                <div class = "col-md-12"></div>
                <div class = "col-md-5 col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                    <div class = "card">
                        <div class = "card-header">
                            LOG-IN
                        </div>
                        <div class = "card-body">
                            <div>
                                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                {{ render_field(form.email, class = "form-control") }}
                                {{ render_field(form.password, class = "form-control") }}
                                {{ render_field(form.remember_me, class = "form-control") }}
                                {{ render_field(form.submit, class = "btn btn-primary") }}
                            </div>
                            <p>Don't have an account? <a href = "{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Sign-Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock app_content %}
```

python file where I put my attributes:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, IntegerField, PasswordField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, length, email, EqualTo

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    fname = StringField("First Name", validators = [DataRequired(), length(min = 2, max = 20)])
    lname = StringField("Last Name", validators = [DataRequired(), length(min = 2, max = 20)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators = [DataRequired(), email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators = [DataRequired()])
    phoneno = StringField("Phone Number", validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField("Password", validators = [DataRequired(), EqualTo("password")])
    submit = SubmitField("Signup")

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField("Email", validators = [DataRequired(), email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators = [DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField("Remember Me")
    submit = SubmitField("Login")
```

So my issue is, the form is successfully created and well with input areas where users enter their email, phone number, etc, with the titles of each entry area on top of it so for example an email entry bar would have "'email' written on top of it". However, it is black and I want it to be white as my background is black.

I am confused as to how I can refer to these texts which are on top of the entry areas because I am using WTForms and as you can see, they are not really in a class or anything. I have a style section in my html where I am doing my styling where for example I have referred to the form itself by adding '.form-control' etc, but that doesnt affect the text.
How do I refer to this text in my style section, or is there any other way I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can create a class for the parent div and then in your CSS file, assign that class a color. This will make the form labels like "email" that given color but will also make the form input text (what the user inputs) as that same color. For example:

```
<div class = "login-form">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ render_field(form.email, class = "form-control") }}
  {{ render_field(form.password, class = "form-control") }}
  {{ render_field(form.remember_me, class = "form-control") }}
  {{ render_field(form.submit, class = "btn btn-primary") }}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.login-form {
  color: white;
}
```

**Option 2**

Edit "_formhelpers.html" template and assign different class attribute values to each of the tags, then assign colors to those specific classes. For example:

Edit the "_formhelpers.html" file

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <div  class="form-label-example">
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-example">
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
      {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </dd>
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Edit the CSS

```
div.form-label-example {
  color: white;
}

div.form-field-example {
  color: black;
}
```

Note that the existing "form-control" label that you have is using bootstrap (if it's imported in your file) and thus will overwrite the custom coloring of the form field inputted text, but the title labels will still have the custom coloring you assigned in the CSS.

Comment: So I had tried option 1 before posting and it hadn't worked, but I tried your option 2 and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!